# Передача Console как параметра C#

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, консоль

(Название темы некорректное, за что прошу прощения, по другому не знал как назвать)

Есть функция `Read()`, как параметр она принимает объект класса `StreamReader`. Но мне иногда нужно считывать данные из консоли и хотелось бы передать поток консоли как параметр для считывания информации.

```
class A
{
    public void Read(StreamReader str)
    {
        //тут код чтения в стиле
        string s = str.ReadLine();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
class Proga
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Read(/*тут поток, который передаю*/);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить `StreamReader` на более общий `TextReader`:

```
class A
{
    public void Read(TextReader str)
    {
        //тут код чтения в стиле
        string s = str.ReadLine();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Тогда можно будет использовать [`Console.In`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
class Proga
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Read(Console.In);
    }
}
```